# Hough Transform with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I need to detect the x-axis and y-axis on a diagram. Existing libraries for PHP cannot detect the lines as this process requires Hough Transform method (please correct me if I am wrong) Is there any way to detect the axises with/without Hough Transform using PHP.

an example to the diagram:
[image]

Comment: I think you're probably going to find it difficult to do that using using PHP natively. I'd recommend you take a look at using OpenCV if possible: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ I'd be keen to here if there is a better way though.

Comment: If the axises always form a right angle and follow the x and y directions of an image, it might not at all be that hard to fulfill. Even a simple process like counting the vertical and horizontal pixels could suffice to find these axises. Also if this is not the case, a hough transform might even be quite fast, if you know that the image will never be turned around more than +/-10°, because you can decrease the loop of the angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if the goal is the detection of the axis only, an easier approach would be using morphological operations (using hough transform could be really computationally demanding, and possibly wouldn't work with so much "noise"). I would rather use [GNU octave](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gnu%20octave&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/&ei=0GwUT7rKGenf4QSMhfj7Aw&usg=AFQjCNEypt0LX5CcG5RPaBFrZWEO7QbRMg&sig2=i4bLOXRDVeBUMiKtob5lfA&cad=rja) to do the image processing operations, than serve the results through a php frontend.

Possible code for starting could be (e.g. to detect origin and maximum values - filter for minimal x, maximal x, minimal y, maximal y to get the corners):

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('iEth9.jpg'));
I = I < 11;
A = imopen(I, ones(1,100)');
B = imopen(I, ones(1,100));
imagesc(I);hold on;
[y,x] = find(A&B);
plot(x,y,'ro');
```

Comment: I cannot upload images due to some error in my inernet connection, but here is the output of my example (sorry for the quality) http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/272/examplefg.jpg

Comment: WebMonster, thank you! I will also run your script. I might have a few more questions.

Comment: Gnu octave keeps giving the following message: "error: rgb2gray: the input must either be an RGB image or a color map". How can I convert the current image to rgb format?

Comment: What is the result of size(I), after I = imread('<filename>')? If it's height x width only (not height x width x 3) your file is alredy a grayscale image, so you could skip the rgb2gray step.

Comment: I tried without rgb2gray and this is the result http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/410/gnuoctave1.png. I don't know why I couldn't get the same result as yours.

Comment: You forgot the transpose (') from matrix A.